# Does the javascript Date() function return local time?

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
var date = new Date();
```

Would date be relative to the users local timezone?

Comment: No but whatever the system clock is on that computer, so mostly yes but no

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, in fact it would be identical to the user's own computer time. It doesn't take the information from the server or anything, but from the user's own computer.

Answer (score 3):

"The expression new Date() returns the current time in internal format, as an object containing the number of milliseconds elapsed since the start of 1970 in UTC. **So timezone issues do not apply. They become significant if you convert the time to a string**."

Yes, the time returned by the ***new Date()*** expression doesn't consider timezone issues, only when it is converted to a string.

```
> d = new Date()
Thu Feb 07 2013 11:48:47 GMT-0200 (BRST)
```

My timezone is GMT-0200.

```
> d.toISOString().substr(0,19)
'2013-02-07T13:48:47'
```

As we can see, the time returned does not consider the timezone.

To consider the timezone internally:

```
> d = new Date()
Thu Feb 07 2013 11:51:49 GMT-0200 (BRST)
> d = d - (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
1360237909163
> d = new Date(d)
Thu Feb 07 2013 09:51:49 GMT-0200 (BRST)
> d.toISOString().substr(0,19)
'2013-02-07T11:51:49'
```

Now the time is adjusted to my timezone.

I was having serious problems with this in a camera monitoring software that saves recordings. How my timezone is GMT-0200, after 22:00 hours the recordings files were being put in the day after folder. I was using the ***new Date()*** expression to get the date folder name where the recordings were being saved.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `new Date()` returns the current time in internal format, as an object containing the number of milliseconds elapsed since the start of 1970 in UTC. So timezone issues do not apply. They become significant if you convert the time to a string.

In practice, the value obtained is of course an approximation based on the client computer’s clock. It may or may not be synchronized with an external time server that provides a fairly accurate time, but it’s still a matter of “client time” as opposite to time on a www server.