# How can i make this countdown work for other timezones?

Tags: javascript, html

Im setting up a new years countdown (bit late i know) but i would like to know how to get this to work for other timezones

I have already got it working for the usual UTC timezone as thats default. I have tried the .toLocalString and it returned NaN on the countdown

```
var countDownDate = new Date("Dec 31, 2018 23:59:02").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 
60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Happy New Year!";
    done()

  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: only thing is, im hosting it on 000webhost and i dont know if that will work

Comment: It's not related to the server. it'll run on user's browser.

Comment: If this code intended to run in browsers it can run in local time.

Comment: if you are not using node.js, then yes it is run in browsers. Your can change the timezone of your computer to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Date function of javascript returns local time of each timezone depending from where the page is loaded. So you don't have to keep track of each timezone
[explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926236/does-the-javascript-date-function-return-local-time)

Comment: Yes that is correct. Javascript dates depends on user's browser.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry i am new to web developing and everything!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with moment.js easily:

```js
var tz = moment.tz.guess();
console.log("Current Timezone: " + tz);
var last = moment.tz("2018-12-31 23:59:02", tz);
setInterval(function(){
    var current = moment.tz(tz);
    if(current.isBefore(last, "seconds")){
        var diff = moment.duration(last.diff(current));        
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = diff.days() + "d " + 
            diff.hours() + "h " + diff.minutes() + "m " + diff.seconds() + "s";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Happy New Year!";
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: changed setTimeout to setInterval.

Comment: Did you press "Run code snippet" and wait for a second?